# Vertically aligning h2 and p tags in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get the words 'method' and 'text' to vertically align in the 'affiliates-methodology-text' div but can't get it to work. I've tried aligning vertically, wrapping the text in a block, setting the line height, looking at other very similar threads, etc but can't get it working either way. Can anybody please help? note that this is a template and where it says 'text' will have a description longer than 1 line

The code is below, or find it here: jsfiddle.net/bxvge3rh/

```
HTML:

<div class="affiliates-methodology-wrap">
       <div class="affiliates-methodology-text">
       <h3 class="affiliates">Method</h3>
       <p class="affiliates2">text...</p>
       </div>
       <div class="affiliates-methodology-picture"></div>
       </div>


CSS:

.affiliates-methodology-text{
    width:810px;
    height:150px;
    background:#039;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}
.affiliates-methodology-picture{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:#9F0;
    float:left;
}
.affiliates-methodology-wrap{
    background:#F00;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to vertically along in the middle?

Comment: related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1)?

Comment: Do you mean horizontally? They are aligning vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the display: table; and display: table-cell; properties.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLd3z3mt/1/

HTML

```
<div class="affiliates-methodology-wrap">
   <div class="affiliates-methodology-text">
       <div class="outerDiv">
           <div class="valign">
               <h3 class="affiliates">Method</h3>
               <p class="affiliates2">text...</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="affiliates-methodology-picture"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.affiliates-methodology-text{
    width:810px;
    height:150px;
    background:#039;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
.outerDiv {
    display: table;
}
.valign {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: center !important;
    padding-top: 40%;
}
.affiliates-methodology-picture{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:#9F0;
    float:left;
}
.affiliates-methodology-wrap{
    background:#F00;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: the text needs to be vertically aligned, not the divs

Comment: Don't use important.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean horisontal alignment of the header and paragraph tag you can use the inline method of the display property, like this for example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h3>Some h3 tag</h3>
    <p>Some p tag</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
// All child elements inside the div with class 'wrap' will display as inline
.wrap > * {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with flexbox.

```
.affiliates-methodology-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```